# Why is this code not running the way it should. Please explain

Tags: javascript

I expect the output to be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, but the actual output is 0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,1...... Can anybody explain why?

```js
function foo(iteration) {
  if (iteration === 5) {
    return;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    foo(iteration + 1);
  }
}
foo(0);
```

Comment: Step through it with a debugger and it will be clear. You first enter `foo`, go into the `for` loop, print `i = 0`, recursively call the function, enter `foo`, go into the `for` loop, print `i = 0`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a level and build a visual result of the call.

As you see, you start every new level with `i = 0` and iterate each level five times. Then result is something like 5<sup>5</sup> iterations.

```
iteration
|   i
|   -----------------
0   0
1       0
2           0
3               0
4                   0
4                   1
4                   2
4                   3
4                   4
3               1
4                   0
```

```js
function foo(iteration, level = 1) {
    if (iteration === 5) return;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        result += iteration + i.toString().padStart(4 * level) + '\n';
        foo(iteration + 1, level +1);
    }
}

var result = '';
foo(0);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```